# Funny ASPX handling by IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

*[This might be better on serverfault, if so, I'll move the question over there - but thought there's more asp.net devs here so more chance of this behaviour having been seen by someone else]*

I've been trying to track down the .NET setting in IIS that governs this behaviour, but with no luck...

In brief, we have a Server 2008 R1 box running IIS7. When we navigate to a URL of the form: http://server/path/webpage.aspx/webpage.aspx, it processes the page correctly and returns the correct response. If I try this with a static HTML page or an ASP page, I get a 404 (expected).

It seems that there's no limit to the level of repetition ... http://server/path/webpage.aspx/webpage.aspx/webpage.aspx/webpage.aspx all runs as if we'd gone to the right URL in the first place (i.e., just a single webpage.aspx).

This is (or at least should be) a default configuration of IIS. Anyone any ideas whether we've got a box that's tweaked in some odd way?

**Edits/answers to questions [last edit @ 16:55]:**

- Using .NET 2.0
- IIS Application Pool is configured as 'Classic' pipeline
- IIS configured for anonymous access; using a classic (legacy) ASP front-end for authentication
- This is a mixed app: we have many legacy ASP elements as well as several ASP.NET elements.
- No custom HTTP modules are used

Ultimately this isn't causing a problem functionally: but it does mean log analysis is being thrown off, and if we can switch off this (rather unexpected) behaviour it'd be useful.

Comment: Are you using any custom HTTP modules?

Comment: @David - No [updated question accordingly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not IIS7 specific, but IIRC a feature of the way ASP.NET works: the script identified by the first `.aspx` will handle the request, and get a `/webpage.aspx` as the `Request.PathInfo`; this would happen to anything starting with a `/` after an ASP.NET page name, such as `.aspx` and `.asmx`, pages. So the following url is also handled by `webpage.aspx`: http://server/path/webpage.aspx/foobar.

If you look at `.asmx` web services, you'll find that the sample requests use such urls: http://server/path/service.asmx/WebMethodName.

Comment: Ahh... 'k. The repeated ASPX name was a red-herring. Just dropped random stuff after the / and yep, it ignores it (as we don't use PathInfo). Ta :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more info:

1) Version of ASP.NET

2) IIS Application Pool and is it integrated or classic

3) Using no authentication, windows autehntication or forms